# Is $H^1(M) \subset L^2(M) \subset H^{-1}(M)$ a Hilbert triple for $M$ a manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Is $H^1(M) \subset L^2(M)  \subset H^{-1}(M)$ a Hilbert triple for $M$ a manifold with boundary? What smoothness is required of the boundary? I would be grateful for some references to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a sufficient condition is that (it is highly probable this is not necessary): Whenever the smoothness of $\partial M$ supports a Poincaré type inequality:
$$
\|u\|_{L^2(M)}\leq c\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(M)},
$$
then the Hilbert triple
$$
H^1(M)/\mathbb{R}\subset L^2(M) \subset H^{-1}(M),\quad \text{ or }\quad H^1_0(M)\subset L^2_0(M) \subset H^{-1}(M)
$$
holds.

The first inclusion is dense due to the fact that $C^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^2$.

Second inclusion holds if Poincaré inequality on this manifold holds for $H^1(M)$: for $\phi\in L^2(M)$
$$
L_{\phi}(u) := \int_M \phi u \leq \|\phi\|_{L^2(M)}\|u\|_{L^2(M)} \leq c\|\phi\|_{L^2(M)}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(M)},
$$
thus $\phi\in H^{-1}(M)$.

I checked Evans's PDE book, the proof of Poincaré inequality relies on Rellich–Kondrachov compact embedding theorem, which normally assumes the boundary is Lipschitz. In [Sobolev met Poincaré](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/HajlaszK-SobolevMetPoincare-test-MemoirsAMS-145-2000-no.688-101pp.pdf), the assumption is weakened to twisted cone condition for a domain (see 9.2), I am guessing this condition should be able to be extended to a compact manifold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the first inclusion really trivial? Is it obvious that the inclusion is dense?

Comment: @maximumtag $C^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^p$. :)

Comment: I know that's true for the standard open bounded set case but was unsure in the hypersurface case. I guess I should not worry too much :P

Comment: @maximumtag The density result definitely holds for smooth and compact manifold with a boundary, for it looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$ locally. But it is not trivial though, roughly the proof should be: $u = \sum_{i} \phi_i u$, where $\{\phi_i\}$ are a partition of unity, also $\phi_i$ has support within an open neighborhood so that we can fix a chart on this, then we can initiate the standard density in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The existence of this partition of unity relies on compactness I believe.

Comment: Thank you.  Presumably smoothness of the manifold can be weakened.  Any idea where to find a proof of this result? I guess one is expected to just patch it together like you said.

Comment: @maximumtag I believe Hebey's notes Sobolev Spaces on Riemannian Manifolds should have addressed the density problem, I will check the library tomorrow.